# How to addObserver for location services of device on/off

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an ios app and i want to notify my app when location services of device turn on/off. when my app is not running.

Comment: I tried didAuthorizationChange() method but it doesn't work on background state and then i do some research on it and i find addObserver pattern that will notify when a value of variable gets change. Then i make a variable of type bool and assign it to [locationManager locationServicesEnabled] and put add observer on this variable but it didn't work. So i need help regarding this scenario.

Comment: Where's your code for what you have tried? Please update your question with what you have tried

Comment: bool locationAuthenticationChange=[locationManager locationServicesEnbled];

[[CLLocationManager locationManager] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"locationAuthenticationChange" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];

I am getting an error in the above statement that "No known class method for selector 'locationManager'  "

Answer (score 0):

You can't get that notification when your app is not running. It's not possible.

When your app *is* running, you can be notified by creating a `CLLocationManager`, setting its delegate and implementing the `-locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` method

Comment: Is there Anyway to handle this scenario:

I am working on an ios app related to tracking(location updates) and tracking is starting on receiving a notification. In this, I want to handle a scenario that the location services of the device are off and tracking notification is received. then after some time user go to setting and turn on location services of device and doesn't launch my app. so is there any way to get location updates?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to register for significant-change location with `-startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` but if you do that while location services are off it will probably fail to start. Try it and see.